# MATLAB index within groups

Tags: matlab

Given a vector `A` of group numbers (such as the one returned by `findgroups`), how to return a vector `B` of the same length containing indices of elements within groups of `A`?

For example, if `A = [1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2]` then `B = [1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 4 5]`.

**Add 1**

My own solution to this is

```
s = splitapply(@(x) {x, [1:numel(x)]'}, [1:numel(A)]', A(:))
B(vertcat(s{:,1})) = vertcat(s{:,2})
```

but it seems somewhat convoluted.

Comment: Can you provide what was the original input which was grouped using `findgroups` to get the vector `A` in your example?

Comment: It could be anything, e.g. A = findgroups(C) where C ={'CAT', 'CAT', 'CAT', 'DOG', 'DOG', 'DOG', 'CAT', 'CAT', 'DOG', 'DOG'}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `sort` and `accumarray`:

```
[s is]=sort(A);
idx = accumarray(s(:),1,[],@(x){1:numel(x)});
B(is)=[idx{:}];
```

Another solution using the image processing toolbox:

```
p=regionprops(A,'PixelIdxList');
B = zeros(size(A));
for k = 1: numel(p)
    B(p(k).PixelIdxList) = 1:numel(p(k).PixelIdxList);
end
```

Comment: I like the use of `sort` and, in particular, its second output argument to return the positions.

Comment: This is not too dissimilar from what I was trying out, but it seems to be about 3 times faster.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that may not look as compact, but it's quite fast since it uses [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) and indexing:

```
mA = max(A);
nA = numel(A);
ind = false(mA, nA);
ind(mA.*(0:(nA-1))+A) = true;
B = cumsum(ind, 2);
B = B(ind).';
```

And here are some timing results for the solutions thus far:

```
A = [1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2];

rahnema1: 6.51343e-05
    Luis: 3.00891e-05
     OmG: 2.36826e-05
 gnovice: 4.93539e-06  % <---

A = randi(20, 1, 1000);

rahnema1: 0.000274138
    Luis: 0.000257126
     OmG: 0.000233348
 gnovice: 9.95673e-05  % <---

A = randi(20, 1, 10000);

rahnema1: 0.00162955
    Luis: 0.00163943
     OmG: 0.00126571
 gnovice: 0.00107134  % <---
```

My solution is the fastest for the above test cases (moderate size, moderate number of unique values). For larger cases, other solutions gain the edge. The solution from [rahnema1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47638193/52738) seems to do better as the number of unique values in `A` increases, whereas the basic for loop from [OmG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47637882/52738) does better when the number of elements in `A` increases (with relatively fewer unique values):

```
>> A = randi(200, 1, 100000);

rahnema1: 0.0108024  % <---
    Luis: 0.0931876
     OmG: 0.0427542
 gnovice: 0.0815516

>> A = randi(20, 1, 1000000);

rahnema1: 0.131256
    Luis: 0.171415
     OmG: 0.106548  % <---
 gnovice: 0.124446
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that avoids loops:

```
s = bsxfun(@eq, A(:).', unique(A(:))); % Or, in recent versions, s = A==unique(A).';
t = cumsum(s,2);
B = reshape(t(s), size(A));
```

Comment: Thanks. The proposed solution seems to depend on the orientation of `A` and more importantly, it creates an intermediate results `s` of size `numel(A) * numel(unique(A))` which might be quite large in practice.

Comment: @Confounded I solved the orientation issue. You should have stated in your question that the vector can be a row or a column

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be using a loop to replace the values in `A`:

```
c = unique(A);
B= A;
for (idx = c)
    f = find(A == idx);
    B(f) = 1:length(f);
 end
```